# Flashing UEFI firmware on a Chromebook?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, flash, chromebook, steam-os

I have flashed SeaBIOS on my Acer C710 (Parrot) Chromebook so I can use/install most any OS I want. However, now, I'm trying to install SteamOS on an external HDD but to do that, I have to boot the USB installer in UEFI. SeaBIOS is a legacy BIOS (right?) so I need to flash a different BIOS to install Steam to the external HDD.

I've been looking around and the best thign I've found is [TianoCore](http://www.tianocore.org/) but I can't find any instructions on how to flash it.

Also, if/when I flash it, it would wipe my Chromebook's memory, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to install the "Full ROM" version of the Mr Chromebox firmware.  This is the version which provides UEFI support but also removes the ability to boot ChromeOS.  Your c710 is compatible with this version.

https://mrchromebox.tech/#firmware